# Hibernate Collection is always empty when performing insert and read in same method/transaction

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to create a Hibernate entity and then read a one-to-many Collection in the same method/transaction and its always returning empty for the get Collection call. I've tried to use an `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` instead of `fetch=FetchType.LAZY` and I've also tried a Hibernate `flush()` after the car insert and before the car read, but the one-to-many Collection is always empty.  If I remove the get Collection call (see getCarList() below) and put it in another method, the Collection is not empty but I would like to keep the insert and read in the same method if possible.  I have also tried calling `Hibernate.initialize(this.carList)` but still empty.  Ideas?

**Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "car_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Car {
  private Car defaultCar;
  private List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>();

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "DEFAULT_CAR_ID")
  public Car getDefaultCar() {
    return defaultCar;
  }

  public void setDefaultCar(Car defaultCar) {
     this.defaultCar = defaultCar;
  }

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "defaultCar", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  public List<Car> getCarList() {
    return carList;
  }

  public void setCarList(List<Car> carList) {
    this.carList = carList;
  }

 @Transient
 public void initializeCarList() {
    Hibernate.initialize(this.carList);
 }
```

**Service Implementation:**

```
public List<Car> saveAndGetDefaultCarList(){
Car car1 = new Car();
carDAO.create(car1);

Car car2 = new Car();
car2.setDefaultCar(car1);
carDAO.create(car2);

List<Car> defaultCarList = car1.getCarList(); //always returning empty List
}
```

**DAO Implementation:**

```
    public class CarDAOImpl implements CarDAO {

        private DaoFactory daoFactory;

        @Override
        public Copy create(Car car) {
            GenericDao<Car> dao = daoFactory.getDao(Car.class);
            return dao.create(car);
        }

        public void setDaoFactory(DaoFactory daoFactory) {
            this.daoFactory = daoFactory;
        }

        public void setCarDao(CarDAO carDAO) {
            this.carDAO = carDAO;
        }
    }

        public class HibernateDaoFactory implements DaoFactory {
            private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
            private HibernateSessionConfigurer sessionConfigurer;

            public <T> GenericDao<T> getDao(Class<T> clazz) {
                HibernateDao<T> dao = new HibernateDao<T>(clazz);
                dao.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
                dao.setSessionConfigurer(sessionConfigurer);

                return dao;
            }

            public QueryDao getQueryDao() {
                HibernateQueryDao dao = new HibernateQueryDao();
                dao.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
                dao.setSessionConfigurer(sessionConfigurer);

                return dao;
            }

            public void flush() {
                sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
            }

            public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf) {
                this.sessionFactory = sf;
            }

            public void setSessionConfigurer(HibernateSessionConfigurer cfg) {
                this.sessionConfigurer = cfg;
            }
        }
```

**Library Versions:**

```
hibernate-core-4.2.0.final
spring-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
```

**Spring Hibernate Config:**

```
<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  </bean>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
      <tx:method name="create*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>  
    </tx:attributes>
  </tx:advice>
```

Comment: Could you post carDAO create() method?

Comment: @MGorgon added DAO classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your car1 is this same object as it was before `car2.setDefaultCar(car1)`, because `car2.setDefaultCar(car1);` updates only car2 instance. What you want, is to update car1 state (fetch changes from database), after storing car2 in database.
To do it in one method, you need to flush() session (or commit) and call `refresh(car1)` method on car1  instance - it will be recreated from database.

But, there is other approach - first add car2 to car1 collection, and then just persist car1 - this will cause that car2 will be persisted also (when `cascade="save-update"` is set).

Comment: the flush and refresh worked fine but I'm more interested in your second solution.  I tried to implement it but I'm getting a InvocationTargetException when trying to persist car1.  I created a car1 instance, created a car2 instance, set car2.setDefaultCar(car1), then car1.getCarList().add(car2), then carDAO.create(car1).  I added @OneToMany(mappedBy = "defaultCar", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL) to the getCarList(). Was that what you meant for me to do?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you have inversed the relation ship from one-to-many side, but has not defined the relationship owner many-to-one side.

You have inversed the relationship. So the One-to-many side does not own the relationship. The owner would be the property "defaultCar"

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "defaultCar", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  public List<Car> getCarList() {
    return carList;
  }
```

But you have not annotated the defaultCar with ManyToOne

Try defining the owner of the relation properly

Comment: I forgot to include the ManyToOne in my original post but have added it now.